# how to scroll a position which i have created on a login screen

Tags: flutter

```dart
Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                height: 500,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xff0A7FD3),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(80),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(80),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 80,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
                  // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                          blurRadius: 15,
                          spreadRadius: 5),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage('imagedirectory/image/encap.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                          child: Text(
                            'ENCAPSULATOR',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 26,
                                color: Color(0xff266089),
                                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                          child: Text(
                            'Digital Time Capsules',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: Color(0xff898787),
                                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0xff979393),
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            ),
                            labelText: 'Email',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0xff979393),
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            ),
                            labelText: 'Password',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                        child: Center(
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              // Navigator.push(
                              //   context,
                              //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Submit()),
                              // );
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              'Forget password?',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: Color(0xff716B6B),
                                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Color(0xff0A7FD3),
                            onPrimary: Colors.white,

                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
                            minimumSize: Size(400, 60), //////// HERE
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Get.toNamed('dashboard');
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            'SIGN IN',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 22,
                              fontFamily: 'Lato',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              color: Color(0xffffffff),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                          child: Text(
                            'Don’t have account',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: Color(0xff474444),
                                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Get.toNamed('signup');
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              'Request to register',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: Color(0xff529C00),
                                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

i want to scroll position over another position in login screen

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I not getting wrong your question should be like below 
**how to make stack positioned scrollable**

Only define  `bottom: 0,`

```
Positioned(
    top: 280,
    bottom: 0,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
        // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                blurRadius: 15,
                spreadRadius: 5),
          ],
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Center(
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('imagedirectory/image/encap.png'),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                  child: Text(
                    'ENCAPSULATOR',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 26,
                        color: Color(0xff266089),
                        fontFamily: 'Lato',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: Text(
                    'Digital Time Capsules',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Color(0xff898787),
                        fontFamily: 'Lato',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Color(0xff979393),
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                    labelText: 'Email',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Color(0xff979393),
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                child: Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      // Navigator.push(
                      //   context,
                      //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Submit()),
                      // );
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Forget password?',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Color(0xff716B6B),
                        fontFamily: 'Lato',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Color(0xff0A7FD3),
                    onPrimary: Colors.white,

                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
                    minimumSize: Size(400, 60), //////// HERE
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text(
                    'SIGN IN',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      color: Color(0xffffffff),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                  child: Text(
                    'Don’t have account',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Color(0xff474444),
                        fontFamily: 'Lato',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      'Request to register',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Color(0xff529C00),
                        fontFamily: 'Lato',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```